# How to ignore a class in build time Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, aidl

I have a multi-module project (two other Android applications has been added as submodule and library). When I want to build the project, get a duplicate entry error: 
    `com/name/pc/IManagerService$Stub$Proxy.class` 
because of AIDL's generated files in both the main module and submodule. I've already build this project successfully with target SDK version 25 but when I change min and target SDK Versions to 19 build fails because of the above error.
Is there a way to exclude this file in gradle to ignore it or other solution to solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can change your module when you run by changing the run configuration in run tab

**Run > Edit Configurations >**

In **general** select the module that you want to run and click **ok**

now this help you run witch module you want to run.